# Добавления стрима с YouTube на свой сайт

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, html5

Можно как-то добавить стрим человека на свой сайт, а именно чтобы когда он начинал свой стрим то он автоматически добавлялся на сайт? Я искала в интернете информацию на счёт этого ну там только как добавить видео или стрим которые уже давно опубликованные и делать это нужно в ручную что мне не подходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить информацию о текущих прямых трансляциях другого канала, вы должны использовать стандартный поиск [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs):

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channelId}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

где, параметры должны быть заданы следующим образом:

```
part      = snippet
eventType = live
type      = video
channelId = [ID канала/пользователя на которм проходят стримы]
key       = [ваш API_KEY]
```

Comment: А можно боле точный пример на основе любого канала, я просто не очень поняла?

Comment: Сначала нужно зарегистрироваться в `console.developers.google.com`, создать проект и получить API_KEY. Затем читать документацию Youtube API. По ссылке все написано, разобраться там несложно, если есть навык в веб-разработке.